# Prove that $G$ is soluble if and only if it has a subnormal series 1 $\leq G_1 \leq \cdots \leq G$ such that $G_i/G_{i+1}$ is abelian.

Tags: group-theory, solvable-groups

Prove that $G$ is soluble if and only if it has a subnormal series $1 = G_0 \leq G_1 \leq \cdots \leq G_n = G$ such that each factor $G_i/G_{i+1}$ is abelian.

Since $G$ is soluble, then we have derived series $G \geq G^{(1)} \geq \cdots \geq G^{(k)}=1$. Also $G^{(i)}/G^{(i+1)}$ is abelian.

How should I continue with the proof to show that the series is subnormal? And also the other way of proof?

Comment: That the series is subnormal is trivial since otherwise the statement that the quotients are abelian would make no sense. For the other direction, remember that a normal subgroup with abelian quotient must contain the commutator subgroup. Then repeat.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft So is it right to let $G_i = G^{(n-i)}$ then proceed to get the series given in the question? For the other direction, do you mind to explain the statement as I couldn't see how it works from there? Thank you.